# Why is my Entity Framework connection string not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to connect to a database without using App.Config but i keep getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.

I can't see where I've gone wrong so i thought i'd ask here.

```
namespace MyNameSpace
    {
        using System;
        using System.Data.Entity;
        using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
        using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

        public partial class Entities : DbContext
        {
            public Entities()
                : base(entityString.ToString())
            {
            }

            public static EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityString = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder()
            {
                Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0",          
                Metadata = "res://*/RS.csdl|res://*/RS.ssdl|res://*/RS.msl",
                ProviderConnectionString = @"C:\RestOfPath\database.sdf;Password=3476dfg423434563466e85rcsd"
            };  



        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing your `sdf` file directly on your connection string. Try changing:

```
ProviderConnectionString = @"C:\RestOfPath\database.sdf;Password=3476dfg423434563466e85rcsd"
```

To:

```
ProviderConnectionString = @"Data Source=C:\RestOfPath\database.sdf;Password=3476dfg423434563466e85rcsd"
```

Or better yet, use a `SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder` to construct this property:

```
var connectionStringBuilder = new SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder();
connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = @"C:\RestOfPath\database.sdf";
connectionStringBuilder.Password = "3476dfg423434563466e85rcsd";
EFConnectionBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString(),
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it was something simple!

Comment: What got me was that in your question you specified: `Additional information: The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.`. Are you sure it didn't say `Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open`? The first message sounds weird and I've never seen it :-)

Comment: Ty for the updated answer, That will make the next step easier! Cheers!

Comment: It most certainly said "ConnectionString" i copy and pasted it, I didn't find much googling it.

Comment: That is weird! Then again, I haven't mangled a lot with Ce :-)
Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Try this : make this parameterise

```
    public Entities(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    {
    }
```

and pass string connection string when creating object of Context class.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
 Entity _context = new Entity("data source=Dev-4;initial catalog=test1;
 integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;  
 App=EntityFramework");
}
```

Comment: That won't work because then i have to pass the connection string every time i create a new instance.

Comment: try this :     public Model1()
        : base(connString)
    {
    }

    public static string connString = "data source=tesst;initial catalog=test1;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";

Answer (score 0):

Try this : here you din't need to pass connection string again and again -->

```
    public Model1()
        : base(connString)
    {
    }

    public static string connString = "data source=tesst;initial catalog=test1;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
```

Use This method when using Database First Model of Entity Framework :

```
    public test1Entities()
         : base(nameOrConnectionString: ConnectionString())
    {
    }

    private static string ConnectionString()
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = "DEV-4";
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = "test1";
        sqlBuilder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();
        entityBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/";
        entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";

        return entityBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You have to use EntityConnectionStringBuilder when using a Database first model, This was the first thing i tried, It didn't work.

Comment: Hi, please check another method written by me, this will working when using Database First Model.

Comment: Please note : Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" in my original post. Also, This doesn't account for the password.

Comment: please try this : public Entities()
        : base(new SqlCeConnection("--string connection string--"),
             contextOwnsConnection: true)
    { }

Comment: I reckon that would probably work but i prefer the answer from Jcl.